# What happens to @data@values when adding large rasters in R?

Tags: r

Simple arithmetic operations work as expected with small rasters, for example:

```
> r1 <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
> r1[] <- rep(1, 5 * 5)
> class(r1@data@values)
[1] "numeric"
> class((r1 + r1)@data@values)
[1] "numeric"
```

But when I use bigger rasters, strange things happen:

```
> r1 <- raster(ncol=5000, nrow=5000)
> r1[] <- rep(1, 5000 * 5000)
> r2 <- r1 + r1
> class(r2@data@values)
[1] "logical"
```

Why did `r2@data@values` become `logical`?
This resulting object is unusable in subsequent calculations,
and in general it's behaving strangely, for example:

```
> summary(r1@data@values)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       1       1       1       1       1 
> summary(r2@data@values)
   Mode    NA's 
logical       0 
> object.size(r1)
200011576 bytes
> object.size(r2)
12112 bytes
```

Basically `r2` looks broken.

As a workaround, adding the `@data@values` seems to work fine:

```
> r3 <- r1
> r3@data@values <- r1@data@values * 2
> class(r3@data@values)
[1] "numeric"
```

But how can you explain this behavior that only happens with larger rasters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `logical` is because the `raster` object points to a temporary file on disk where the actual values are stored, rather  than storing the 25 million numeric values in memory. The values are perfectly usable for subsequent arithmetic methods. Using the `@data@values` slot to set values is asking for trouble. Either use the arithmetic methods provided or use the `setValues()` function.

This is detailed in the `?Arith-methods` help page:

> If the values of the output Raster* cannot be held in memory, they will be saved to a temporary file. You can use options to set the default file format, datatype and progress bar.

Given your `r2` object above, you can use it as you would for an object stored in memory. This is one of a number of things that `raster` does very well - it works seamlessly with files stored on disk, as though they were regular in-memory objects.

```
r3 <- r2^2
r3
#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 5000, 5000, 2.5e+07  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 0.072, 0.036  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
#data source : /private/var/folders/ck/1x5j5jvx5mq17clf5r32gg540000gn/T/R_raster_tmp/Simon/raster_tmp_2014-01-13_214043_710579.grd 
#names       : layer 
#values      : 4, 4  (min, max)
```

Note the value of the layer is correctly returned as `4`, i.e. `2^2`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you explain my result for `summary(r2@data@values)` ? I also cannot do things like `head()` on it and other ways of accessing the values don't work.

Comment: You need to do `head( r2[] , 10 )`. You need to use the `[]` to return the values. The `summary` result comes about because you are getting a logical for each value on disk. You *should* do `summary( r2 )`. Look at `?raster::summary` for more details. There are explicit summary methods written for `raster` objects. Again, don't access the slots directly. The authors dont make guarantees about how changing values via these will behave, hence why accessor functions are provided. Always use these.

Comment: That's pretty clever. Unfortunately, it seems that if I save this object to an `.RData` file and load it later, it won't work anymore. Looks like the temp file where it stored the data gets lost. Is there a way to save a raster so that I can safely load it again later? Or is there a way to disable the use of temporary files? In my example my object is 200MB, not small, but on my PC it's not a problem.

Comment: @janos there is, yeah sure. The problem is you can't do the arithmetic operations in memory because it requires too many copies of the date. TRy `canProcessInMemory(r2, 4)`. Instead, do the calculations, write the raster out to a file using `writeRaster()` and then read it in again with `raster( "myraster.grd" )`. The values will be in memory and will be saved with the `.RData` file (until you need to do some more arithmetic on them).